# How to pop at index in React Native Navigator?

Tags: react-native

I have a problem that by my app design, it's possible to have an infinite route stack of several scenes. This slows the app down severely after some playing around. I want to have a mechanism that whenever a new route is opened, its duplicates in the stack are deleted. I haven't found any function of the Navigator that would do this, only similar is `resetAtIndex` which does not pop however. Is there any trick to do what I want to do?

I still want to keep the order of scenes that user visited, so jumpTo will not do. (example: User goes to A, then to B, C and to B again. I want the stack to look like ACB instead of ABCB)

Comment: If you want it to go back to B then have it .pop() instead of push onto the stack.

Comment: You misunderstood what I meant, maybe the example is too small. In another example, I want from route ABCDEB have ACDEB. In this case, I can't just pop because there are CDE in the stack which I want to keep.

Comment: Ah I get it, I dont think theres anything built in that does that but maybe you can create you're own function that adjusts the routeStack. You can check what's in the stack through navigator.state.routeStack. Then before your move to B you can check if B is in the routeStack and remove it then push B onto the end. You can try it out and test if there's no side effects. If I didn't explain well I can try helping write the function.